is there a programmatic API to access transaction emails opens / clicks / unsubscribes
We have a legacy exacttarget that now exists in SFMC. I have just started working with it but and am trying to maximize our value from it.
We send emails using the FuelSDK and access information for email sends via the Web UI but this is very inefficient via this:

Is there a REST API to access this information per trigger such as opens / clicks per email?
Also, is there a more modern version of sending outgoing emails?
Thanks and this is my first exposure to Salesforce Marketing Cloud so if I am (probably) missing some very obvious issues.

I suggest that you look into the new Transactional Messaging API, which offers an Event Notification Service that has webhooks to notify your external system if emails have been delivered, bounced, opened, etc.

You can use the Send SOAP object data, which is an always fresh, aggregated summary of all send jobs from account inception.
I have blog post about mirroring this data back into a Data Extension, but it should be enough for you to infer the SOAP structure.  Not sure if the SDK supports that object or not.
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1");
var debug = false;

// Mirrors Send SOAP Object data into a data extension
// - creates its own data extension
// - without any date filters includes all sends from account inception

try {

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    var TargetDECustomerKey = 'Send';
    var TargetDECategoryID = // CATEGORY ID OF TARGET DE GOES HERE;

        // CREATE SEND DE
    try {

      var result=prox.createItem("DataExtension",{"CustomerKey":TargetDECustomerKey,"Name":TargetDECustomerKey,"Description":"Send SOAP Object","CategoryID":TargetDECategoryID,"Fields":[
        {"CustomerKey":"ID","Name":"ID","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":true,"IsRequired":true},
        {"CustomerKey":"SendDate","Name":"SendDate","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"EmailName","Name":"EmailName","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"100","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"Subject","Name":"Subject","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"200","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"Status","Name":"Status","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"15","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"Additional","Name":"Additional","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"50","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"BCCEmail","Name":"BCCEmail","FieldType":"EmailAddress","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"Client_ID","Name":"Client_ID","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"Client_PartnerClientKey","Name":"Client_PartnerClientKey","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"64","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"CreatedDate","Name":"CreatedDate","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"Duplicates","Name":"Duplicates","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"Email_ID","Name":"Email_ID","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"Email_PartnerKey","Name":"Email_PartnerKey","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"64","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"EmailSendDefinition_CustomerKey","Name":"EmailSendDefinition_CustomerKey","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"36","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"EmailSendDefinition_ObjectID","Name":"EmailSendDefinition_ObjectID","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"36","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"SendClassification_CustomerKey","Name":"SendClassification_CustomerKey","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"100","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"SendClassification_Name","Name":"SendClassification_Name","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"100","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"SendClassification_Type","Name":"SendClassification_Type","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"100","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"ExistingUndeliverables","Name":"ExistingUndeliverables","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"ExistingUnsubscribes","Name":"ExistingUnsubscribes","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"ForwardedEmails","Name":"ForwardedEmails","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"FromAddress","Name":"FromAddress","FieldType":"EmailAddress","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"FromName","Name":"FromName","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"130","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"HardBounces","Name":"HardBounces","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"InvalidAddresses","Name":"InvalidAddresses","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"IsAlwaysOn","Name":"IsAlwaysOn","FieldType":"Boolean","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"IsMultipart","Name":"IsMultipart","FieldType":"Boolean","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"MissingAddresses","Name":"MissingAddresses","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"ModifiedDate","Name":"ModifiedDate","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"NumberDelivered","Name":"NumberDelivered","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"NumberErrored","Name":"NumberErrored","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"NumberExcluded","Name":"NumberExcluded","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"NumberSent","Name":"NumberSent","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"NumberTargeted","Name":"NumberTargeted","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"OtherBounces","Name":"OtherBounces","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"PartnerKey","Name":"PartnerKey","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"64","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"PreviewURL","Name":"PreviewURL","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"500","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"SendLimit","Name":"SendLimit","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"SendWindowClose","Name":"SendWindowClose","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"SendWindowOpen","Name":"SendWindowOpen","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"SentDate","Name":"SentDate","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"SoftBounces","Name":"SoftBounces","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"UniqueClicks","Name":"UniqueClicks","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"UniqueOpens","Name":"UniqueOpens","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"Unsubscribes","Name":"Unsubscribes","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"CampaignID","Name":"CampaignID","FieldType":"Number","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"0"},
        {"CustomerKey":"CampaignCreatedDate","Name":"CampaignCreatedDate","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"CampaignModifiedDate","Name":"CampaignModifiedDate","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"CampaignName","Name":"CampaignName","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"50","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"CampaignDescription","Name":"CampaignDescription","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"500","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"CampaignCode","Name":"CampaignCode","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"36","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"CampaignColor","Name":"CampaignColor","FieldType":"Text","MaxLength":"6","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"CampaignFavorite","Name":"CampaignFavorite","FieldType":"Boolean","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false},
        {"CustomerKey":"InsertDate","Name":"InsertDate","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false,"DefaultValue":"getdate()"},
        {"CustomerKey":"UpdatedDate","Name":"UpdatedDate","FieldType":"Date","IsPrimaryKey":false,"IsRequired":false}
      ]});

    } catch (e) {

    }

    var sendCols0 = ["Additional","BccEmail","Client.ID","Client.PartnerClientKey","CreatedDate","Duplicates","Email.ID","Email.PartnerKey","EmailName","EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey","EmailSendDefinition.ObjectID","ExistingUndeliverables","ExistingUnsubscribes","ForwardedEmails","FromAddress","FromName","HardBounces","ID","InvalidAddresses","IsAlwaysOn","IsMultipart","MissingAddresses","ModifiedDate","NumberDelivered","NumberErrored","NumberExcluded","NumberSent","NumberTargeted","OtherBounces","PartnerKey","PreviewURL","SendDate","SendLimit","SendWindowClose","SendWindowOpen","SentDate","SoftBounces","Status","Subject","UniqueClicks","UniqueOpens","Unsubscribes"]
    var sendObj = "Send";
    var sendCols = sendCols0;

    // SEND FILTER - IF NEEDED
    var filterDate0 = new Date();
    filterDate0 = filterDate0.setMinutes(0);
    filterDate0 = filterDate0.setSeconds(0);
    filterDate0 = filterDate0.setMilliseconds(0);
    filterDate0 = filterDate0.setHours(0);

    var filterDate = DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(filterDate0);
    filterDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate() - 999);

    if (debug) {
     Write("<br><br>filterDate: " + filterDate);
    }

    var sendFilter = {Property: "SendDate", SimpleOperator: "greaterThan", Value: filterDate};
    //var sendFilter = {Property: "ID", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: 1048264};
    //var sendFilter = {Property: "ID", SimpleOperator: "greaterThan", Value: 0};
    var moreRows = true;
    var reqID = null;
    var opts = { BatchSize: 500 };
    var props = {};

    while (moreRows) {

        moreRows = false;

        if (reqID) {
          props.ContinueRequest = reqID;
        }

        var sendRows = prox.retrieve(sendObj, sendCols0, sendFilter, opts, props);

        if (sendRows != null) {

            moreRows = sendRows.HasMoreRows;
            reqID = sendRows.RequestID;

            if (sendRows && sendRows.Results) {

                for (var i = 0; i < sendRows.Results.length; i++) {

                    var row = {};
                    row.ID = sendRows.Results[i].ID;
                    row.PartnerKey = sendRows.Results[i].PartnerKey;
                    row.CreatedDate = sendRows.Results[i].CreatedDate;
                    row.ModifiedDate = sendRows.Results[i].ModifiedDate;
                    row.Client_ID = sendRows.Results[i].Client.ID;
                    row.Client_PartnerClientKey = sendRows.Results[i].Client.PartnerClientKey;
                    row.Email_ID = sendRows.Results[i].Email.ID;
                    row.Email_PartnerKey = sendRows.Results[i].Email.PartnerKey;
                    row.SendDate = sendRows.Results[i].SendDate;
                    row.FromAddress = sendRows.Results[i].FromAddress;
                    row.FromName = sendRows.Results[i].FromName;
                    row.Duplicates = sendRows.Results[i].Duplicates;
                    row.InvalidAddresses = sendRows.Results[i].InvalidAddresses;
                    row.ExistingUndeliverables = sendRows.Results[i].ExistingUndeliverables;
                    row.ExistingUnsubscribes = sendRows.Results[i].ExistingUnsubscribes;
                    row.HardBounces = sendRows.Results[i].HardBounces;
                    row.SoftBounces = sendRows.Results[i].SoftBounces;
                    row.OtherBounces = sendRows.Results[i].OtherBounces;
                    row.ForwardedEmails = sendRows.Results[i].ForwardedEmails;
                    row.UniqueClicks = sendRows.Results[i].UniqueClicks;
                    row.UniqueOpens = sendRows.Results[i].UniqueOpens;
                    row.NumberSent = sendRows.Results[i].NumberSent;
                    row.NumberDelivered = sendRows.Results[i].NumberDelivered;
                    row.NumberTargeted = sendRows.Results[i].NumberTargeted;
                    row.NumberErrored = sendRows.Results[i].NumberErrored;
                    row.NumberExcluded = sendRows.Results[i].NumberExcluded;
                    row.Unsubscribes = sendRows.Results[i].Unsubscribes;
                    row.MissingAddresses = sendRows.Results[i].MissingAddresses;
                    row.Subject = sendRows.Results[i].Subject;
                    row.PreviewURL = sendRows.Results[i].PreviewURL;
                    row.SentDate = sendRows.Results[i].SentDate;
                    row.EmailName = sendRows.Results[i].EmailName;
                    row.Status = sendRows.Results[i].Status;
                    row.IsMultipart = sendRows.Results[i].IsMultipart;
                    row.SendLimit = sendRows.Results[i].SendLimit;
                    row.SendWindowOpen = new Date(sendRows.Results[i].SendWindowOpen).getFullYear() > 2000 ? sendRows.Results[i].SendWindowOpen : null ;
                    row.SendWindowClose = new Date(sendRows.Results[i].SendWindowClose).getFullYear() > 2000 ? sendRows.Results[i].SendWindowClose : null ;
                    row.IsAlwaysOn = sendRows.Results[i].IsAlwaysOn;
                    row.Additional = sendRows.Results[i].Additional;
                    row.BCCEmail = sendRows.Results[i].BCCEmail;

                    if (sendRows.Results[i].EmailSendDefinition && sendRows.Results[i].EmailSendDefinition.ObjectID && sendRows.Results[i].EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey) {

                        EmailSendDefinition_ObjectID = sendRows.Results[i].EmailSendDefinition.ObjectID;
                        EmailSendDefinition_CustomerKey = sendRows.Results[i].EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey;
                        row.EmailSendDefinition_ObjectID = EmailSendDefinition_ObjectID;
                        row.EmailSendDefinition_CustomerKey = EmailSendDefinition_CustomerKey;

                    }

                    row.UpdatedDate = new Date();

                    var de = DataExtension.Init(TargetDECustomerKey);
                    var rowsAddedUpdated = 0;

                    try {

                      rowsAddedUpdated = de.Rows.Add(row);

                    } catch (e) {

                      try {

                        rowsAddedUpdated = de.Rows.Update(row, ['ID'], [sendRows.Results[i].ID]);

                      } catch(e2) {

                      }
                    }

                } // for-loop

            } // row results


        }

    }

} catch (e) {


}


Thanks Adam - this looks really helpful. I should mention that I'm VERY new to using ExactTarget / SFMC Web UI but have been using the email sending functionality via FuelSDK for a few years. This requires running in Automation Studio and I don't believe I have access to that via the Web UI. Is there any way for me to check whether I have access? Thanks again!
